# why indices are getting deleted from elasticsearch on Sunday 06:00 UTC?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have hosted Elasticsearch and Kibana on a Azure VM. I send application logs to elasticsearch. On every Sunday 06:00 UTC all indices are being deleted from elasticsearch. I checked the index lifecycle policy, there is no index lifecycle policy attached to any indexes. How can I prevent deletion ? any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you having any authentication in your ES cluster if no, check if its due to meow attack, you can follow [elastic blog on the attack and how to prevent it for free](https://www.elastic.co/blog/protect-your-elasticsearch-deployments-against-meow-bot-attacks-for-free).

Comment: there is no authentication on my ES cluster. maybe your assumption is right. but it does not create and leave an index with the -meow suffix. is there any way to check Elasticsearch internal logs - to know what happened on Sunday 06:00 UTC

Comment: @MirSabbir yes, you can check elasticsearch cluster logs easily :) where elasticsearch would also log the deletion index log.

Comment: any documentation how to check internal logs and how to filter by specific time? you know if it's a normal log file on the disk then it's harder to read. @ElasticsearchNinja

Comment: I checked logs. you were right, Thanks @ElasticsearchNinja

Answer (score 3):

We can disable deleting indices using wild cards by setting action.destructive_requires_name property into true.

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
 "persistent": {
 "action.destructive_requires_name": true
 }
}
```

You can also set this setting in elastic search.yml.

This setting is not bound to any index, it works at cluster level. It tells elasticsearch to accept explicit names when deleting indices.